# Multiple IDs in Conceptual Search - Is it and AND operation or an OR operation?

Tags: concept-insights

When I specify multiple IDs as query parameters in my conceptual search, would the results have only those documents which refer conceptually to all of the searched IDs? Or will it have documents that refer conceptually to any one of the IDs?

Thanks
Vipin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intended behavior of passing multiple ids to the `/conceptual_search` query is a logical AND. So the search is trying to find documents that have relationship to **all** the ids listed in the query.

The OR behavior cannot be performed through a single query, but can be emulated by performing separate queries to the individual ids, followed by a merge (with proper sorting) of the results on the client side.